# C - Error in Deleting an Entire BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I can't seem for the life of me figure out what the is wrong with my code in the deletion of a whole BST.

I figure since there doesn't seem to be a problem with this:

```
void emptyTree(BST **root){ 
    if((*root)!=NULL){
        emptyTree(&(*root)->left);
        emptyTree(&(*root)->right);
        free(*root);
    }
}
```

Then the whole problem lies with the initial entry of each node in the tree. Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

```
void insertNode(BST **root, BST *temp){
    if((*root)!=NULL){
        temp->parent = *root;   
        if(((*root)->value) < (temp->value))    
            insertNode(&(*root)->right,temp);
        else if(((*root)->value) > (temp->value)) 
            insertNode(&(*root)->left,temp);
        else if(((*root)->value) == (temp->value)){ 
            printf("The number %i is already in the tree.\n",temp->value);  
            return;
        }
    } else {
        *root = temp;
        printf("%i was added to the tree.\n",temp->value);
        return;
    }
}

void newNode(BST **root, int x){
    BST *newnode;

    newnode = (BST *)malloc(sizeof(BST));
    newnode->value = x;
    newnode->left = newnode->right = newnode->parent = NULL;

    insertNode(root,newnode);
}
```

It compiles, it runs, it does absolutely every function right(including one that deletes one node at a time). Except the 'Delete All'(emptyTree) one. It doesn't delete everything(?). It doesn't even show an error when I run through the emptyTree function. It only errors when I printf the whole tree.

Comment: Well, one thing could be that [in C you should not cast the return or `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You need to step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on - this is much more productive than trying to guess what's wrong by looking at the code (or asking others to do the same).

Comment: You state there is something wrong. How do you know that? Does it compile? Run? Delete files instead?

Comment: Can you also add a `main` that shows, for a few items, how you use `newNode` and `insertNode` as well as `emptyTree` that (1) compiles and (2) shows the problem? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you *do* free all data, but forget to indicate that your elements no longer contain valid data.
That is, after deleting, all elements' `left` and `right` members, and your own `root` itself still contain *a* value; they still contain the original values, but these no longer point to valid, allocated, memory.

The error does not directly occur within `emptyTree` because this works from the end nodes up to the top, and there is no reason to check "down". But as soon as you attempt to *print* `root` (and its descendants), you are accessing unallocated memory.

Insert

```
*root = NULL;
```

in your `emptyTree` function after

```
free(*root);
```

to fix it inside the `emptyTree` function, or set `root` to NULL after calling `emptyTree`.

Personally, I prefer the former, even though it's a minor overhead. That way, you only have a single function to delete a tree, instead of the recursive one plus a wrapper that also sets the root to NULL.

Comment: I wrote *root=NULL there a few mins after i posted this question, but I wasn't sure if it actually deallocated or if its just linking to NULL and thus losing the entire tree. Thank you for the clarity :)

Comment: Yes, you need both. `free(x)` marks the pointed-to memory as *free* but it does nothing to `x`. `x=NULL;` does the oppposite; *you* say that you don't need the pointer anymore, but the memory block stays allocated and cannot be free'd in any way.